# Why sorting by group.key changes the order of the previously ordered dataset? How to avoid it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
                    query = from q in query
                    orderby q.Student.StudentDate descending
                    group q by q.Student.StudentName
                    into qGroup
                    orderby qGroup.Key
                    select qGroup
                    .OrderBy (s => s.Student.RoleId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                     var studentStates = query
                    .Skip((model.pageNumber - 1) * model.pageSize)
                    .Take(model.pageSize);
```

Since before grouping I want the records to be ordered descending by `StudentDate` and it works but the problem is

```
orderby qGroup.Key
```

which again changes the order so If I remove this then another issue occurs which is `Skip()` and `Take()` which needs an ordered list to process.

What do I do here?

Comment: It can't be both linq-to-sql and entity-framework. Which of the two do you use?

Comment: With EF the ordering by `StudentDate` would be ignored, irrespective of later ordering. EF ignores all ordering before `GroupBy`. If the ordering by `StudentDate` really works (when not ordering by `Key`) I assume it is linq-to-sql after all.

Comment: But if order the set by subjectdate; later in the code ; it becomes very slow even it is the indexed field. Literally, tried everything

Answer (score 0):

With Linq queries that end up on a SQL Server I tend to avoid using *FirstOrDefault()* in combination with *group by*. And write my queries in a manner more custom to how SQL queries are written.

Try using the Composite Key feature of Linq (See the Microsoft documentation) by introducing an anonymous type. The type will never be instantiated, it is just an abstraction to describe what you want.

```
query = from q in query
    group q by new { 
        q.Student.StudentName, 
        q.Student.StudentDate,
        q.Student.RoleId }
    into qGroup
    orderby qGroup.Key.StudentDate descending
    select qGroup.Key.RoleId;
```

The student name must be included in the grouping, in case there are two students with the same Date and RoleId. The StudentDate and RoleId can't make the grouping more unique since the depend on the StudentName, which is the primary key of Student.

I assumed here that in the final result only the RoleId was needed, since that is the only field you used in the select clause. Although the intent is not totally clear to me.

If more fields are needed in the final result you could create a class that encapsulates those fields and construct it in the select at the end. Like this:

```
    select new MyClass { Name = qGroup.Key.StudentName, RoleId = qGroup.Key.RoleId };
```